# How to draw line pass through point and center of rectangle?

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

There is a point A and quadrilateral with Longitude and latitude, I calculate the center of quadrilateral C, then I want to draw a line pass through A to C and extend that line to -20 latitude B, how can I calculate the coordinate of point B?[image]

Comment: Your question is too broad. Have a look at the Google Maps Geometry Library. It has many helpful methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define quadrilateral for a sphere.
2. Find C, the center.  Or at least approximate it.  For example avg lat and avg lng might be "close enough".
3. Convert A and C to [x,y,z] assuming center of earth is [0,0,0].
4. You now have 3 3D points.  This defines a circle on the plane that goes through all 3.
5. Find the plane where B is.  Note that this latter plane does not go through [0,0,0]; instead [0,0,z] where z is some simple trig based on -20 deg latitude.
6. Find the line that intersects those two planes.
7. Find, on the line, the x,y for the above z.
8. Convert [x,y,z] to polar to get longitude.

(Sorry, I don't have the energy or incentive to fill in the details.)

(There could be a simpler algorithm, but I doubt if it would have many fewer steps.)